# Can I use manual socks proxy for only specific sites?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, tunnel, socks5

I am using socks proxy with chrome. With dconf editor, I can add ignore-host so that browser connect this hosts without proxy. Now I want to do opposite of this. I mean I want to specify hosts so that browser connect only these hosts by proxy. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firefox or Google Chrome or Chromium browser, you could use FoxyProxy (free as of 26-Oct-2015) to use a manually configured proxy for specific URLs.

To configure which sites you want to access using the proxy, click on the [FoxyProxy Standard](http://getfoxyproxy.org/downloads.html) icon besides the address bar, click on "Add New Proxy" and then configure your host, port no, username and password and configure the URLs in the "URL Patters".

Refer [the quickstart page for FoxyProxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/quickstart.html) for more.

**P.S.:** This has been tested to work on Firefox 29(which has the enhanced UI)!

Comment: I realized that foxyproxy is also available for chrome and explorer...